# Is there a variable like @@ServerName but for the database name?

Tags: sql-server-2008

I need to get the name of the database I am currently running against (to use in a URL column).

I know I can get the server name by using @@ServerName.  But there is no @@DatabaseName.

How can I get the database that is currently being run against?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try using this:

```
select DB_Name()
```

An example where the database changes:

```
use master
select DB_Name()
use model
select DB_Name()
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use DB_NAME() to get the database name.

```
SELECT DB_NAME() AS DataBaseName
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this function to get the database name which you are currently using

**select DB_NAME()**